# memory leak error when redirect to home if user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I've trying to redirect to home if user is not logged in(status 401) in componentDidMount.

So I tried

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const requestPatientListApi = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await get<AxiosResponse<PatientApi>>("/patient", { requester: "admin" });
        return data.items;
      } catch (err) {
          //when user is not logged in redirect to "./"
          props.history.push("./");
      }
      return [];
    };

    if (!axios.isCancel("")) {
        // updating state when api call is not canceled 
        requestPatientListApi().then(patients => {
          setPatients(patients);
        });
    }
}


  componentWillUnmount() {
      if (cancel) {
        cancel();
      }
  }
```

But, the error occurs:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
```

I've tried using axios cancel token, but it seems not a solution for this case.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're redirecting before setting a state, in which case the component is not rendered anymore. One way would be to forward the error in your async func and catch it later.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const requestPatientListApi = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await get <AxiosResponse<PatientApi>>("/patient", {
        requester: "admin"
      });
      return data.items;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err; // Forward the error further
    }
    return [];
  };

  if (!axios.isCancel("")) {
    requestPatientListApi().then(patients => {
      setPatients(patients);
    }).catch(err => {
      props.history.push("/"); // handle the error here
    });
  }
}
```